# QGIS 3.10 - Python problem with double for loop

Tags: python, qgis-3, for-loop

I am new to Python and I am trying to write a custom function which iterates through a table of points and adds a field with all of the lines that touch it.
At the moment I am getting a partially right answer but there is some repetition going on.

An extract of the code:

```py
 Homelayer = iface.activeLayer()
 Hfeatures = Homelayer.getFeatures()
 layerSet = {layer.name():layer for layer in qgis.core.QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()}
 targetLayerName = 'PRECABLE'
 targetFieldName = 'PF_PERE'
 for feature in Hfeatures:
    tst = []
    for feat in layerSet[targetLayerName].getFeatures():
        geom = feature.geometry()      
        if geom.touches(feat.geometry()):
            run = feat.attribute(targetFieldName)
            tst.append(run)
            res = ','.join(tst)    
            print(res)
```

The result I get is:

> XX1710
>
> XX1710,XX1711
>
> XX1710,XX1711,XX1712
>
> XX1710,XX1711,XX1712,XX1713
>
> XX1710,XX1711,XX1712,XX1713,XX1714
>
> XX1710,XX1711,XX1712,XX1713,XX1714,XX1715
>
> XX1710,XX1711,XX1712,XX1713,XX1714,XX1715,XX1716
>
> **XX1710,XX1711,XX1712,XX1713,XX1714,XX1715,XX1716,XX1717**
>
> XX1717
>
> XX1717,XX1721
>
> XX1717,XX1721,XX1722
>
> **XX1717,XX1721,XX1722,XX1723**

I just need the lines in bold.

Answer (score 2):

You should just align `print` statement with inner `for` loop. In Python, `if` and `for` statements don't define a scope. So `res` variable is visible outside of the `if` and `for`.

```
for feature in Hfeatures:
    tst = []
    for feat in layerSet[targetLayerName].getFeatures():
        geom = feature.geometry()      
        if geom.touches(feat.geometry()):
            run = feat.attribute(targetFieldName)
            tst.append(run)
            res = ','.join(tst)    
    print(res) # unindentation
```